# How To Create Facebook Application programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a facebook app from within my code.

When done manually, I have to go to developers.facebook.com, go to the apps section and click on "create a new app". This will create a new app and facebook will ask me to provide the basic information like

- App display name
- App namespace
- Site url
- canvas url

This will create a new app.

I want to do the same automatically. Is it possible with RestFb?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is, **NO** you can't do that by any Facebook method and the reason for the same is similar to the reason that due to which you can't create Page, Facebook user account, Group through Facebook's API and it is security which other poster has listed out.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. If you could do it by code you could atuogenerate infinite apps automatically. It will be a dangerous security hole to facebook. So, you have to do it manually.